# Is html5lib vunerable to malicious input?

Tags: python, html5lib

Python's [XML Processing Modules](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities) documentation lists vulnerabilities in its XML processing modules. I would assume that html5lib is not similarly vulnerable to malicious input as it follows the HTML5 spec (unknown bugs aside), but I hate making assumptions and I can't find discussion of potential security issues.

So are there any security issues I should be aware of? Or is it safe to use it to parse maliciously constructed html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no (at least that anyone is aware of) — the XML attacks take advantage of "features" of XML that don't exist in HTML. (Technically, "decompression bombs" apply to almost any formats, and aren't really attacks on XML — they're attacks on decompressors.)